# ec2 instance unreachable from browser with rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

First, i read everything i found about my problem but i am still stuck,
so i launch my ec2 instance, with the good security group with the port 80 open, ssh as well (22) and ICMP (-1)

[image]

i can ping the ip, it works well, i can ssh, no problem, when a `wget http://localhost` on this instance it's working as well

It's a rails application i launch `sudo rails s -p80` (to be on the port 80) but i have a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

when i nstat on my instance i got this :

[image]

so i guess the port 80 is not open but i have no idea how to fix this.

Anyhelp ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Rails 4.2.x? It defaults to listen on only the localhost interface. You can use `sudo rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p80` to tell it to listen on all interfaces and it should be accessible externally.

Comment: OMG thankkkkkkks it's working fine ! i was going crazy

Comment: Great! If you are happy with the answer please upvote/accept it :)